# Webview in Android 4.4 logs nativeOnDraw failed

Tags: android, video, webview

This question has been asked many times, but none of the answers works for me.
I'm using webview playing video  url = "http://youtu.be/gm4wlE04hbI" , the webview does not work and turn blank, it logs

```
01-30 00:00:31.640: W/AwContents(16221): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
```

My layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_base_top_bar" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         >
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>`
```

And the code
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_content);

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            L.e(newProgress + "");
        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

And close the hardware

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

I hope some could tell me what's wrong with it ....